I am struggling compiling Android project in Android Studio with Dagger/Hilt and Proguard
So I am pretty new to Android Studio, and Android development; my background is Java fullstack.
I started by creating a default template from Android Studio and moved my code (and code from a dagger sample project, and sample code from the API I'm trying to implement).
In terms of classes and events I think I have everything correct, but my project is not compiling.  When I say run with stack trace, the error I get is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
...
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid relative name: META-INF\proguard\com_inventoryscanner_ui_barcodescannerBarCodeScanningViewModel_HiltModules_BindsModule_LazyClassKeys.pro
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid relative name: META-INF\proguard\com_inventoryscanner_ui_barcodescannerBarCodeScanningViewModel_HiltModules_BindsModule_LazyClassKeys.pro
I am using
Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 3
Gradle 8.11.1
AGP 8.7.3
Java 11
SDK 35
Target 30
[libraries]
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltVersion" }
hilt-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltVersion" }
hilt-android-gradle-plugin = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "hiltVersion" }
dagger-android-processor = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "dagger-android-processor", version.ref = "hiltVersion" }

[plugins]
dagger-hilt-android = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hiltVersion" }

kotlin = "2.0.0"
hiltVersion = "2.53"


App level
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.android) apply false
}

Module level
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.android)
    kotlin("kapt")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.inventoryscanner"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.inventoryscanner"
        minSdk = 30
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdk = 30
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled = true
        resourceConfigurations += setOf()
        proguardFiles()
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    buildToolsVersion = "35.0.0"
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.livedata.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.legacy.support.v4)
    implementation(libs.androidx.fragment.ktx)
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    implementation(libs.hilt.android.gradle.plugin)
    kapt(libs.dagger.android.processor)
    kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}

hilt {
    enableAggregatingTask = true
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

The proguard-rules.pro file is empty, or at least everything in there is the default commented out template, I haven't touched it.  But I have tried copying settings from some places that hasn't made a difference and then I reverted them.
I've searched online high and low and have tried changing versions, settings, all to no avail.  But I'm new to Android Studio, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

Have the same issue. It seems to be an issue with local machine rather then the project, because on my team mates machine build works just fine. I'm using Windows, she has mac. Started to happen after dependency update to kotlin 2.1.0, dagger 2.53, still investigating the cause

So the problem is not in caches or something. And from what I see it is related somehow to hilt view models injection.

I cannot reproduce the issue; your setup works fine for me.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

So my steps to reproduce are:

Having Windows 11 machine (works fine on macOS)
Kotlin 2.1.0, using kapt for Hilt processor
Having Dagger and Hilt 2.53
Having ViewModel injected with Hilt

Fix is:

Downgrade Dagger and Hilt to 2.52
Downgrade Kotlin to 2.0.21

I think this can be a related issue. Seems that its going to be fixed in 2.53.1

So my mistake is assuming if something goes wrong, to update everything to the latest version...

I think this solved that problem, I followed your suggestion, and that particular error doesn't show anymore.
I get this error now "cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method." which I suspect is an annotation issue my side that I will investigate on Monday.

This seems to be a new problem with dagger 2.53.1 and kotlin 2.1.0 https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/4533
